# Comma-separated column into new column as integer

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to split a comma-separated column into rows without affecting other columns.

My table ....

```
+-----+--------------+------------+-------------+
| id  | parent_title | account_id |    tags     |
+-----+--------------+------------+-------------+
| 647 | title999     |         64 | 361,381,388 |
| 646 | title998     |         64 | 361,376,388 |
+-----+--------------+------------+-------------+
```

Expected table......

```
+-----+--------------+------------+------+
| id  | parent_title | account_id | tags |
+-----+--------------+------------+------+
| 647 | title999     |         64 |  361 |
| 647 | title999     |         64 |  381 |
| 647 | title999     |         64 |  388 |
| 646 | title998     |         64 |  361 |
| 646 | title998     |         64 |  376 |
| 646 | title998     |         64 |  388 |
+-----+--------------+------------+------+
```

Comment: What SQL DB are you working on? Some DBs have a Split() function which does exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: String id's as comma separated values is very bas database design. You should normalize your tables.

Comment: I am using mssql DB, 
actually i'm using split with while loop to do this work, but time taken to exec is very high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get yourself a good string splitting function. No database should be without one.

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Then, do this (note this assumes you've built one of the string split functions and it's called SplitStrings_CLR())

```
;with t as
(
    select id = 647, parent_title = 'title999', account_id = 64, tags = '361,381,388' union all
    select id = 646, parent_title = 'title998', account_id = 64, tags = '361,381,388' 
)
select 
    id,
    parent_title,
    account_id,
    x.*
from t
cross apply sysmon.dbo.SplitStrings_CLR(tags, ',') x
```

Comment: i never worked on CLR functions .. could you please refer any tutorial.. link you gave asking me to register . :(

Comment: Then don't build a CLR. Use one of the sql-based functions. The article I linked you is arguably the best article on the web regarding string splitting functions in SQL Server. If you need to build a split function, I'd recommend spending 20 seconds to register with the site.

Answer (score 0):

Use `XML` trick to do this.

```
SELECT id,
       parent_title,
       account_id,
       Split.a.value('.', 'Int') tags
FROM   (SELECT id,
               parent_title,
               account_id,
               Cast ('<M>' + Replace(tags, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data
        FROM   [table]) AS A
       CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```

[**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/17be17b/1)